# Why does create a user fail

Tags: sql-server

I have restored a database but the owner is 'dbo'; I wish to change the owner to 'dba'.
I have tried: sp_changedbowner dba,true; it run successfully but I can't login as dba.
I then tried:

1. open the database
2. expand security
3. right click, choose 'New', then choose 'User'
   Entries Under General tab are:
4. User type is: SQL user with login
5. User name: dba
6. Login name: dba
7. Default schema -> left blank
   I did NOT make any other entries on the remaining tabs.
   When I click ok, I get this message:
   TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

---

Create failed for User 'dba'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.47021.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+User&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

The login already has an account under a different user name. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15063)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-15063-database-engine-error

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I am confused by this message: "The login already has an account under a different user name.".
How do I resolve this?

Thanks

I tried to create a 'dba' user in the restored database but was unable to do so.
See above

Comment: What error do you get when you can't login as dba? The database owner cannot be added as a database user because the owner is already mapped implicitly to the 'dbo` user inside the database. Maybe not related to your problem but instead of the deprecated `sp_changedbowner` proc, use `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO dba;`

Comment: Dan: I  get this error message: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to MSI.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'dba'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: I also tried: "ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO dba;" but get the same result.

Comment: The SQL Server error log will have more detailed information on the failed login attempt. Perhaps a user named `dba` exists in the database but is orphaned due to a restore to a different server. In that case, drop the user (`USE YourDatabase;DROP USER dba;`) and retry `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`.

Comment: I deleted ALL versions of SQL Server Management Studio and related programs, cleaned up registry rebooted my laptop.

Comment: I then installed this:  Free Download for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.12.1; I was looking to install Configuration Manager but looking on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16 I don't see an entry for MY version of SSMS (18.12.1).

Comment: Where or what  is the CORRECT version of Configuration Manager for my situation??

Comment: SQL Server Configuration Manager is installed with the database engine on the database server. It's unrelated to SSMS, although old SSMS versions used to allow you to launch the tool.

Comment: Dan: in my case, SQL Server is installed on MY laptop, not on a network server. I still believe that I need to configure Configuration Manager.

Comment: The SQL Server Configuration Manager version is aligned with the SQL Server version installed on your laptop. You can use the latest in the SysWow64 directory.